# Dynamic namespaced controllers w/ fallback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a somewhat bizarre requirement for a new Rails application. I need to build an application in which all routes are defined in multiple namespaces (let me explain). I want to have an application in which school subjects (math, english, etc) are the namespaces:

```
%w[math english].each do |subject|
  namespace subject.to_sym do
    resources :students
  end
end
```

This is great and it works but it requires me to create a namespaced `StudentsController` for each subject which means if I add a new subject then I need to create a new controller.

What I would like is to create a `Base::StudentsController` and if, let's say the `Math::StudentsController` exists then it will be used and if it doesn't exist, then we can dynamically create this controller and inherit from `Base::StudentsController`.

Is this something that is possible? If so then how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: I'd just create all of the namespaced controllers and have them inherit from the base controller. Then override as necessary.

Comment: I realize I can do that but that's going to give me a lot of controllers that will only contain the class declaration. Also, if I have 20 controllers and I want to add a new `subject` then I need to copy 20 controllers.

Comment: Right, I see. Is this an actual requirement or is it just an experiment? Because the fluidity of "math", "english" and whatever else comes along doesn't lend itself to namespacing. What about inverting it (students/math)? At that point, what you've really got is a controller action. Now *that* might lend itself better to dynamicism.

Comment: This is a requirement (not mine but rather my many bosses).

Comment: Can you say a little  more about what you mean by "dynamically create this controller"?

Comment: @KyleDecot What is the goal here? Is this for URL presentation, or is there an actual organizational need to segregate business logic into many namespaces?

Comment: The goal is to namespace all `subjects` into their own namespace. A lot of subjects will share common logic between them but in some cases customizations need to be made. I need to be able to add new subjects as easily as possible while still being able to override controllers when needed.

Comment: @Kyle Decot: This looks like a pretty popular question, think it deserves to have a marked answer (even if it's your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing some custom logic into `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.controller_reference`. I attempt to look up all of the constants required for the given controller and create them if they're missing. This code is **FAR** from perfect so please feel free to edit w/ improvements.

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher

  private

  def controller_reference(controller_param)
    const_name = @controller_class_names[controller_param] ||= "#{controller_param.camelize}Controller"

    obj = Object
    const_name.split('::').each do |cn|
      begin
        obj =  obj.const_get(cn)
      rescue
        if obj == Object
          obj =  obj.const_set(cn, Class.new(ApplicationController))
        else
          puts "Creating #{obj}::#{cn} based on Generic::#{cn}"
          obj =  obj.const_set(cn, Class.new("Generic::#{cn}".constantize))
        end
      end
    end

    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.constantize(const_name)
  end

end
```

Comment: Take another look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16511066/712765) and I think you will like it even more.

Answer (score 3):

With routes defined this way:

```
%w[math english].each do |subject|
  scope "/#{subject}" do
    begin
      "#{subject.camelcase}::StudentsController".constantize
      resources :students, controller: "#{subject}::students", only: :index
    rescue
      resources :students, controller: "base::students", only: :index
    end
  end
end
```

`rake routes` outputs:

```
students GET /math/students(.:format)    base::students#index
         GET /english/students(.:format) english::students#index
```

if english/students_controller.rb is present and math/students_controller. is absent.

Comment: This seems rather verbose and this would need to be done for _every_ single resource in my application.

Comment: I can only suggest creating method like this http://pastebin.com/rLLZpCYx, but I guess you won't be satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will do it:

```
  %w[math english].each do |subject|
    namespace subject.to_sym do
      resources :students
    end
  end

  match ':subject/students(/:action(/:id))' => 'base/students'
```

With these combined routes, `/math/students` goes to the `Math::StudentsController`, `/english/students/` goes to the `English::StudentsController`, and all other subjects (e.g. `/physics/students` and `/cs/students`) go to the `Base::StudentsController`.

Which I think is ***exactly*** what you want and only adds one line of code to your original solution.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your answer to my situation, which is very similar, except that I have a lot of custom routes in my namespace. I'm getting an error `uninitialized constant Portals::V1` though and I'm not sure I fully understand how your solution works. My setup is similar except that my dynamic namespace is nested within a primary namespace that doesn't change. I have a set of controllers that are namespaced and want each dynamic sub-namespace to reference those controllers.

Comment: So for example, `/portals/example1` and `/portals/example2` should both go to `general#home` in the `controllers/portals/general_controller.rb`

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH that's too complicated to discuss in comments. Ask a new question if this one doesn't give you the information you need. Refer to this question in your new question and explain why the answers here don't work for you. Of course, be sure to read *all* the answers to this question first.

Answer (score 3):

To restate your requirements:

1. Minimal declarations per subject/resource pair
2. Use dedicated controller (`Math::StudentsController`) if it exists, otherwise use base controller (`StudentsController`)

Rails expects each route to have a dedicated controller, and doesn't really have a good way to support the second requirement. So, this is how I would do it:

```
Dynamicroutes::Application.routes.draw do
  SUBJECTS = [ "math", "english", "chemistry" ]
  RESOURCES = [ "assignments", "students" ]

  class DedicatedSubjectResourceControllerConstraint
    def initialize(subject, resource)
      @subject = subject
      @resource = resource
    end

    def matches?(request)
      begin
        defined?("#{@subject.capitalize}::#{@resource.capitalize}")
        return true
      rescue NameError
        Rails.logger.debug "No such class: #{@subject.capitalize}::#{@resource.capitalize}"
        return false
      end
    end
  end

  class ValidSubjectConstraint
    def matches?(request)
      return SUBJECTS.include?(request.path_parameters[:subject])
    end
  end

  SUBJECTS.each do |subject|
    RESOURCES.each do |resource|      
      namespace subject, :constraints => DedicatedSubjectResourceControllerConstraint.new(subject, resource) do
        resources resource
      end
    end
  end

  RESOURCES.each do |resource|
    scope "/:subject", :constraints => ValidSubjectConstraint.new do
      resources resource
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a use for `const_missing`. If what you want to do is

> to create a Base::StudentsController
>
> and if, let's say the Math::StudentsController exists
>
> then it will be used
>
> and if it doesn't exist, then we can dynamically create this controller and inherit from Base::StudentsController

You can achieve that by adding dynamic constant lookup (`const_missing`) and dynamic constant definition with inheritance (`Object.const_set`).

I imagine something like this; with a few tweaks and more rigorous checking, would work:

```
# initializers/dynamic_controllers.rb

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet

  SUBJECTS = [ "math", "english", "chemistry" ]

  def const_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if SUBJECTS.any?{ |subject| name.include? subject.uppercase }
      Object.const_set name, Class.new(Base::StudentsController)
    else
      super
    end
  end
    
end
```

That'll add dynamic constant lookups to `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet`, from which `Dynamicroutes::Application.routes` inherits, so undefined constants in `Dynamicroutes::Application.routes.draw` will generate the corresponding classes subclassed from `Base::StudentsController`.

Comment: I've added this initializer and restarted my application but this doesn't seem to be getting called. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure. Let me create a dummy app to play around in.

Comment: I've gotten this close to working, using `def Object.const_missing`.

Answer (score 1):

All the routing helpers like `resources`, `scope`, etc are just functions inside your application's routes. You could just define a custom function as follows:

```
YourApplication.routes.draw do

  # Let's define a custom method that you're going to use for your specific needs
  def resources_with_fallback(*args, &block)
    target_module       = @scope[:module].camelize.constantize
    target_controller   = "#{args.first.to_s}_controller".camelize
    fallback_controller = args.last.delete(:fallback).to_s.camelize.constantize

    # Create the target controller class
    # using fallback_controller as the superclass
    # if it doesn't exist
    unless target_module.const_defined?(target_controller)
      target_module.const_set target_controller, Class.new(fallback_controller)
    end

    # Call original resources method
    resources *args, &block
  end

  # Now go ahead and define your routes!

  namespace "test" do
    namespace "new" do
      # Use our custom_resources function and pass a fallback parameter
      custom_resources :photos, :fallback => 'base/some_controller'
    end
  end

end
```

I tested this in Rails 3.2, but it should equally work well in all 3.x versions.

I included no null checks or `begin/rescue` blocks anywhere. Since you're going to use this custom function only when required, I'm assuming that you will pass the correct and necessary parameters. If say you passed a `fallback` controller that doesn't exist, I'd rather that the routes parsing fail with an exception, rather than trying to handle it.

Edit: Typo in function arguments

Edit 2: Forgot `&block` in function arguments

Edit 3: Add "_controller" to the `target_controller` variable

Comment: Note: `@scope[:module]` is a built-in variable in the Route class in Rails. I'm using it to get the current module that we're nested into. The same `scope` is also used by the `resources` function, and most other functions within the routes file.

Comment: This doesn't work for the OP or for me.  It doesn't work for the OP because he wants to be creating top-level constants so `@scope[:module].camelize.constantize` generates an error (uninitialized constant). It doesn't work for me because even if `Test` is defined, this fails because `@scope[:module]` == 'test/new', not 'test'. Yes, you could fix these problems, but now it's getting complicated and it is generating fake classes so they can receive messages that are being meta-programatically generated in the first place.  Too much magic.