# Dynamic name-spaced controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I'm trying to set up a dynamic namespace in Rails and I want each namespace to have dynamically generated controllers from a base set of controllers, or to just refer to the base controllers.

The namespaces will be based off a `Portal` model's name. Each namespace will be functionally equal to any other. The only differences will be with the layout theme, and I want to accomplish that by setting things like theme colors based off the model's attributes.

The namespaces will all be nested under a parent namespace called `portals`.

Here is my `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :portals do
    Portal.all.each do |client|
        namespace cient.name.to_sym do
            root 'general#home'
            get '/companies' => 'general#companies'
            get '/favorites' => 'general#favorites'
            get '/new_favorite' => 'general#new_favorite'
            get '/remove_favorite' => 'general#remove_favorite'

            get '/carousel_items' => 'general#carousel_items'
            get '/user_dashboard' => 'general#user_dashboard'
            get '/get_pag_num' => 'applications#get_pag_num' #get pag num setting from system

            post '/searches' => 'general#post_searches'
            get '/searches' => 'general#retrieve_searches'
            delete '/searches' => 'general#delete_searches'

            #company applicants dash
            # get '/assess_applicants' => 'applications#assess_applicants'
            get '/*compname/compdashboard' => 'applications#assess_applicants'

            # refer a friend email path
            post 'send_refer_a_friend_email' => 'general#send_refer_a_friend_email'

            #withdraw app

            get '/user_apps' => 'applications#user_apps'
            #company dash emails

            resources :applications do
                member do
                    put '/withdraw_app' => 'applications#withdraw_app'
                    put '/remove_app' => 'applications#remove_app'
                    put '/comp_remove_app' => 'applications#comp_remove_app'
                    put '/refresh_app' => 'applications#refresh_app'
                    put '/set_viewed' => 'applications#set_viewed'
                    put '/save_notes' => 'applications#save_notes'
                    put '/decline_app' => 'applications#decline_app'
                    put '/accept_app' => 'applications#accept_app'
                    #emails
                    post '/send_user_app_declined_by_comp_email' => 'applications#send_user_app_declined_by_comp_email'
                    post '/send_user_app_viewed_email' => 'applications#send_user_app_viewed_email'
                    post '/send_user_app_accepted_email' => 'applications#send_user_app_accepted_email'
                end
            end
            get ':id' => 'companies#profile'
        end
    end
    match '/portals/:company(/:action(/:id))' => 'base/portals', via: [:get, :post]
end
```

All of my portal controllers are namespaced like so: `Portals::GeneralController < ApplicationController`. I also want to recycle all the code in `app/views/portals`.

I've been reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468030/dynamic-namespaced-controllers-w-fallback-in-rails/16511066#16511066), which seems very similar to my situation, but I've been struggling to adapt the solutions to my app.

**UPDATE WITH WORKING CODE**

Based on the answer by [kobaltz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722274/kobaltz) I came up with this route structure, which works perfectly for my needs.

```
namespace :portals do
    resources :clientportals do
        member do
            root 'general#home'
```

This results in the following routes being generated:

```
GET    /portals/:clientportals/:id(.:format)    portals/general#home
```

I could use `FriendlyIDs` to shorten the path, but each portal instance will live as a subdomain of the client's site, so that part doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be outside of what you want to do since it can potentially change the scope of your application quite a bit.

Why not use something like

```
resources :portals
    root 'general#home'
    get '/companies' => 'general#companies'
    get '/favorites' => 'general#favorites'
    get '/new_favorite' => 'general#new_favorite'
    ...
end
```

From here you can use `friendly_id` and a slug attribute on the Portal model.

Within your controllers, you can set the layouts which will give you the functionality that you're looking for without the complexity of having so much `magic` going on.

I do like what you're doing as a conceptual piece, but sometimes complicated code is bad. When possible, I will go for readability over DRY.

Comment: That makes more sense to me as well and it seems to be working. I'll post an updated code snippet in my question. I used `resources :portals` and then `members do` inside that and now it seems to be working. Each instance is also using the base set of portals controllers like I'd hoped for. Thanks!